# How to find out team name from BPM instance id

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

Is there a way to get the team an instance is assigned to from the instance id in BPM 8.5.6 version? before a user from the team claims the task I need to auto select some fields on the coach. Is there a way I know which team an instance or a task is assigned to? IS there a way other than REST API.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear in the API documentation, but the TWTask appears to have an attribute "displayName". So the following seems to work -

```
tw.system.findTaskByID(68507).assignedTo.displayName
```

That gave me the expected value, where as "name" gives the internal name which has a GUID on it. Mine was assigned to "All Users". YMMV depending on if it is assigned to a Team, a Role, or a Participant Group.

As it isn't in the JS-API documentation you might want to get an official support statement from IBM. I've seen working items like this stop working, and when you file an issue they point out that the item was not documented, so the fact that it broke is not technically a regression.

Answer (score -1):

There is a REST API available, under REST interface for BPD-related resources --> Process Instance Resource --> Current State. This api will provide all the details for the instance including the vairable, tasks (open & closed).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSV2LR/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/rest/bpmrest/rest_bpm_wle_v1_process_instanceid.htm

Comment: The question specifically requested an non-REST API answer.

Comment: Sorry. If you are planning to achieve in the server script itself, then you can use TWSearch option.